# Is public urination different if there happen to be children around?

Tags: england-and-wales

Bob urinates in an alleyway.

Charles urinates in an alleyway but there happen to be children around the corner or perhaps on the other side of the street.

But Charles certainly didn't have them in mind when deciding to urinate. His concern in all cases was simply to conveniently alleviating his urinary bladder.